# Checking for existance of data from a parameter list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I'm currently working on a project that has me stumped since I haven't done much stored procedure design. I have a task where when entering a user, they can be associated with one or more groups. I am passing the list of groups as a parameter when calling the stored proc as @GroupList = "'Group1','Group2','Group3'". There can be any number of groups. The call for adding a new user should fail if one of the groups doesn't exist. I am attempting to use the following code to check if it exists before populating a temp table with the ID's of the existing groups. My issue is that it keeps failing. I've tried everything I can think of so I am turning to people more skilled than I. Thanks in advance. It is the if exists statement that is failing on me.

```
Declare @GroupList varchar(100), @return int, @sql varchar(1000)
if @GroupList is not null
begin
if (object_id ('tempdb..#TempGroupList') is not null) drop table #TempGroupList
Create Table #TempGroupList
(
GroupID int,
PlayerID int
)
if exists (select * from Group_new where GroupName in (' + @GroupList + '))
    begin
    --lets populate our temp table
        set @SQL = 'insert into #TempGroupList (GroupID) select GroupID from Group_New where GroupName in (' + @GroupList + ')'
        exec(@sql)
    end
else
set @return = 1
select @return
print 'Stop, one of the Group names you entered does not exist'
Return
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would break in input apart, do the check, and then insert:

```
create procedure . . . (
    Declare @GroupList varchar(100),
    @return int, @sql varchar(1000)
) as
begin
    declare table @groups (grp varchar(255));

    insert @groups (grp)
        select ltrim(rtrim(value))
        from string_split(@grouplist, ',');

    if not exists (select 1
                   from @groups g
                   where not exists (select 1 group_new gn where gn.groupname = g.groupname)
                  )
    begin
        . . .  whatever you want to do here
    end;
    else begin
        print 'Stop, one of the Group names you entered does not 
    end;
end;
```

Populating the temporary table defined in the stored procedure doesn't do much, because the temporary table is deleted when the stored procedure returns.  But you can put whatever logic you want in the then part after the `if`.

Comment: You are a god send! Thank you for this, it is so much cleaner than what I was trying to do. It works as expected!